# Authlogic's current_user object in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I need to know the ID of the current user in a model:

```
def after_save
  desc, points=nil, nil

  if answer_index == daily_question.correct_answer_index 
    desc = I18n.t('daily_question.point_log.description.correct') 
    points=daily_question.points
  else
    desc = I18n.t('daily_question.point_log.description.incorrect')
  end

  current_user.give_points(:description => desc,
                           :points => points
                          )
end
```

But I guess that is not how it is done?

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 15, accepted):

assuming the user is loggedin you can use

`UserSession.find.user`

You might want to add checks to ensure `UserSession.find` returns something before calling `.user`

Comment: Wouldn't the current_user be just self? If you call current_user.save somewhere in the controller, then the :after_save :something will know everything about the user... Unless another user can respond as the current_user, you don't really need the "current_user" method I guess...

Comment: I was just trying to figure this out myself.  Thanks!

Comment: This allows fantastic validation methods like *password can be changed only if user == current user*

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.
The current_user relies on the session, which isn't available in the model (and that's normal. The models are context-independent).

You should pass the user to the model as a parameter.

Comment: It is correct in order to remain MVC compliant ... Of course it is technically not correct. That doesn't mean it's good practice.

Comment: I meant that saying "It's not possible" is not correct. I agree with you about the bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access the current_user in the Model(s) when using Authlogic is using Sentiant User - https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user
There is a full documentation on the there how to use it.